# Is Christian Fiction on topic?

Tags: feature-request

Christian Fiction is on the rise. Primarily OT Fiction. [NPR did a report on this](http://www.npr.org/2014/02/02/269550408/amazon-plunges-into-christian-publishing-with-waterfall-imprint). Mesu Andrews talks about what is Xtian Fiction her [Interview video](http://www.christianbook.com/in-the-shadow-of-jezebel/mesu-andrews/9780800721701/pd/721701).

Is this something that is going to be incorporated into this site?

What are the rules for fiction, OT fiction, NT fiction, and/or Xtian fiction? Are you saying it should stay in the Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange Site? This site is strictly non-fiction?

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that Christian fiction, if you are talking about the theology inherent to it, is on-topic. Here's the argument:

1. Theological is explored in a spectrum of written works - defining those rules would be too difficult if we institute a blanket rule.

   Using just C.S. Lewis as an example, he writes everything from Mere Christianity (pure academic apologetics) to The Great Divorce (allegory) to The Screwtape Letters (somewhere between satire and an essay) to The Chronicles of Narnia (clearly fiction).  I doubt any expert would disagree that any of those is not a deep source of theology.

   Allegory, such as Gregory of Nyssa's Life of Moses, clearly straddles the line between fiction and theology - and yet the fact that it is still read more than 1600 years after its composition shows that it is still important.
2. That said, Notability is still important.

   I'd argue that the <strike>crappy</strike> Left Behind series, as flawed as it is, is still on-topic. For many, their eschatology is defined by these books, even over against Scripture.  As such, discussing them would be on topic.  Frank Peretti, while less familiar, is still pretty significant.

   Now, what about [The Noah Movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1959490/)?  My guess is that it is going to be a flaming pile of poo, and will quickly be forgotten.  Is it valuable? Maybe for the few weeks the movie is in theaters, but I doubt it is going to attract experts.  Once people realize how little the movie has to do with Scripture, I think it will become obvious that the film itself belongs on [SciFi as their own meta post exists](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3309/how-will-the-upcoming-noah-film-be-handled).  What little biblical content is in the movie will be on-topic, but "How does this differ from the original?" stays on SciFi or Movies.  My suspicion is [that we've already covered everything](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982/1039) but you know they will come up, and be hated any way..

   [As long as we stay on topic](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/why-do-we-migrate-christian-questions-to-a-christian-audience-about-the-christia/1631#1631), Christian fiction itself is not a limiting factor.  That said, it's about the theology, not the particulars, in which the interest will lie.
3. Finally, defining "Christian Fiction" is going to be interesting.

   I'd argue *Les Miserables* is a work of Christian fiction - but there are a lot of other themes in there too.  *Dogma* raises interesting theological questions, but you won't find it called 'Christian' because it's theology doesn't match up with anything that is actually established doctrine.

   > e.g. The movie Dogma says that God allowed the Pope to set up a situation where God would be wrong. Is that actually Christian?

   I could see that question being on-topic.  That said, "Why did Matt Damon and Ben Affleck choose to be in a movie about Religion? has nothing to do with Christianity, so no - that would be off-topic.

**tl;dr> Christian fiction will probably bring up theology that is on topic, but the label "Christian" itself doesn't inherently make the bar.**

Answer (score 2):

I see the Christianity.SE as a way to learn more about Christian history, doctrine, theology, and practice. Aspects of Christian culture, such as Christian fiction, should go in the Literature.SE or elsewhere on the Internet.

However, this really depends on a case-by-case basis. Maybe the question is really concerned with the truth of the Christian practice that is portrayed in a work of literature and wishes to learn more about it. It does not have to be Christian Fiction, specifically, because any fiction that has Christian practice can pique the reader's interest.

On the other hand, I think questions about fiction should be limited or avoided, because fiction is supposed to be just that: fiction or made up.

Comment: Some fiction authors, such as CS Lewis, are also well known theologians, so there is a gray area, but on the whole, no, fiction is off-topic.