# Where to post question about Christian theological implication of the Narnia stories

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic

Greetings Christian Narnian fans in C.SE !

Has there been an agreement / convention regarding where to post theological questions connecting any of the following:

1. Christian theology
2. The literary universe of the Chronicles of Narnia (the 7 books)
3. C.S. Lewis's personal theology derived from what he said and wrote
4. Essays, writings, interviews, or anything else that either C.S. Lewis / others write about Narnia
5. Our earth-based real universe
6. The worldview of the Biblical authors

I agree with [this answer on Christian Fiction](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/is-christian-fiction-on-topic/3467#3467) clearing this as on topic, but there are also 2 places to post them where they even have the-chronicles-of-narnia tag, but not in C.SE !

- [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-narnia),
- [Lit.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-chronicles-of-narnia)

Between the above two sites, there is a meta post on [Lit.SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-to-decide-where-to-post-questions-that-are-on-topic-for-multiple-sites) about how to choose, but the meta post doesn't include C.SE.

If it is on topic in C.SE, and what are the rules and restrictions?  What tag should I use?  Just **[cs-lewis]**?

Comment: You have enough reputation to make up the tag if desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a tag for any notable work. Chronicles of Narnia would be a fine subject.

I've about [George MacDonald's works](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=george+macdonald) with some success.  I think Narnia would be on topic.

However, I'm a little hesitant about your first bullet point.  I don't think we should be concerning ourselves with all the nautical terms used in the Voyage of the Dawn Treader or why particular birds would speak in a particular way at the Parliament of Owls in the Silver Chair.  I'd leave those questions to Lit.SE or SciFi.SE

Questions here, like you said, should be the Theological Questions and I don't necessarily know how Theological Questions intertwine with the Literary Universe of the books.

Comment: Great.  You: "I don't necessarily know how Theological Questions intertwine with the Literary Universe of the books."  One example is how the character experience heaven (as described in The Last Battle, which is very similar to the Great Divorce).  Although Christianity is relatively silent on the description of heaven, there are some teachings (esp. Catholicism & Orthodox) that describe beatific vision which can be connected with the kids's experience in the books.

Answer (score 1):

**Where to post question about Christian theological implication of the Narnia stories?**

Go for it on main site at Christianity SE. I believe it would be quite on topic.

Here follows a sample question on The Lord of the Rings:

[Who symbolizes Christ in J. R. R. Tolkien's “The Lord of the Rings”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18257/who-symbolizes-christ-in-j-r-r-tolkiens-the-lord-of-the-rings)

If it were me, I would avoid asking the same question on different sites, since cross posting in generally frowned on.

Other than that: Go for it.

Comment: Thanks.  Of course, I wouldn't cross post.  I was careful to ask only intra-universe question in SciFi.SE such as [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228081/how-did-jadis-the-white-witch-obtain-the-right-to-kill-a-traitor-in-narnia).  But if we want to draw parallel between Jadis and the real Satan in our universe, the question belongs to C.SE.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Your welcome. I look forward to a **Narnia** tag.